# Ratpoison under Xfce4

Tags: keyboard-layout, ratpoison, tray

I want to use Ratpoison as WM but I want the DE goodies from Xfce4. That includes

- keyboard layout switching while holding a modifier key, switching back on release *
- tray icon support *
- notifications
- multimedia keys like volume
- gtk skinning

(* means dealbreaker, others nice to have)

Easiest way I guess would be to run Xfce4 as DE replacing the WM with Ratpoison. I have tried and failed getting this to work. Most suggestions mention the use of --replace as an argument to the WM of choice. However, Ratpoison does not come with that feature, at least not what I can find.

```
ratpoison: unrecognized option '--replace'
```

Another way would be to fulfill my requirements above by fitting various hacks into the WM, but that sounds like reinventing the wheel... And frankly I don't know if I'd be able to accomplish it.

All hints to fulfill all or some items of my wishlist is +1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually figured out one way to do it. I simply uninstalled the xfwm4 (in my case `apt-get remove xwm4`), and in Xfce I added `ratpoison` as a startup application. For the traybar I reserved some space by putting the following into my `~/.ratpoisonrc`

```
unmanage xfce4-panel
set padding 0 20 0 0
```

This basically gave me the DE of Xfce4 and the WM of ratpoison. Hence everything solved. I will not accept my own answer though, if someone has a better way of doing it than uninstalling the package.